# PHP -- identifying last key in foreach to eleminate last delimeter

Tags: php, foreach, key

I've been trying to get this to work and while I have tried many methods posted on this site on other pages, I can't get any of them to work.

I need to identify the last key so that my results don't have a , at the end.  This sounds like such and easy task but I just cant seem to get it to work!  At this point I'm guessing I've just had a typo or something that I overlooked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have:

```
<?php
    $searchString = $_GET["s"];  
    $prefix = 'http://link_to_my_xml_file.xml?q=';
    $suffix = '&resultsPerPage=100';
    $file = $prefix . $searchString . $suffix;
    if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file))
        exit('False'.$file);
    foreach($xml->results->result as $item) {
        echo $item->sku . ",";
    }
?>
```

Now this works just fine, it just has a , at the end:

12345,23456,34567,45678,

For reference my xml file is laid out like: results->result->sku, but with a lot more mixed in.  I'm just singling out the  fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider identifying the first instead?

```
$first = true;
foreach($xml->results->result as $item) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
    } else {
        echo ',';
    }
    echo $item->sku;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim)

```
foreach($xml->results->result as $item) {
    $mystr .= $item->sku . ",";
}
echo rtrim($mystr, ",")
```

Should output:

```
12345,23456,34567,45678
```

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/rxOQ45Df)**

Answer (score 0):

If your keys are in numerical order like: 0, 1, 2, 3 etc this could be a solution:

```
foreach($xml->results->result as $key => $item)
{
    if( $key > 0 ) echo ", ";
    echo $item->sku
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution #1:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($xml->results->result as $item) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = false;
    } else {
        echo ', ';
    }
    echo $item->sku;
}
```

Possible solution #2:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($xml->results->result as $item) {
    $items[] = $item->sku;
}
echo join(', ', $items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put everything in a string and then run:

```
substr($yourstr, 0, -1);
```

on your code to remove the last character:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Or get the total number of entries in your array and count your position